# Limit, border or boundary?

Tags: synonyms

Which word is most apt to state that there is a (abstract but definite) border which defines the difference between two religions, philosophies or faiths? Is it limit, border or boundary? 
For example: to accept full responsibility for one's own acts as opposed to considering these (more or less) as a manifestation of the will of God (Allah, or another Supreme Being) can be considered as a defining difference between Humanism (or a humanistic trait in a religion) versus a strict adherence to an orthodox religion. Is this discerning difference of conviction a limit,border or boundary? I am grateful for all views.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [*line*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/line) as it means:

> 19. The official, stated position (or set of positions) of an individual or group, ***particularly a political or religious
>       faction***. From later 19thc.

"Remember, your answers must match the party line." [Wiktionary]

[*Line*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line) also means:

> The boundary or limit of a place. [Merriam-Webster]

If you use an adjective such as "religious/philosophical" before *line*, it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

How about a *line of separation*? Limit implies some sort of inadequacy on behalf of one or both, the end of their reach. If you compare two philosophies without bias, on equal grounds, you wouldn't use something that speaks of them being enclosed or limited, but instead as being unable to communicate with each other because of this separating issue. Borders enclose something, and leave something out, as do boundaries. Anyway, that's my two cents. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a limit, because it can be crossed. I wouldn't call it a border or boundary either, because those are *shared* and imply juxtaposition. *Almost* common ground.

I reckon you want something that stresses the *distance* between faiths, so I'd choose *"gap"*, or (more likely), say it's a **"divide"**:

> a separation of people into two or more groups that is caused by different opinions or beliefs or by a disagreement ( --[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divide))